# Specific heat of vertical copper rod compared to specific heat of horizontal copper rod

Tags: thermodynamics

Both the rods are touching the ground so the vertical rod can only expand upwards. This makes me think that maybe the specific heat capacity is higher. I also feel that the rods should have the same specific heat capacity since they are identical except for their alignment.

Comment: This depends on the variable of specific heat. It could be volume, temperature, pressure etc. The classical definition is temperature in which the extension will indeed be concerned with the alignment in the heat bath for $ \Delta L = \alpha L \Delta T.

Answer (score 1):

The specific heat of the vertical rod is indeed strictly higher than that of the horizontal rod, but the difference may not be measurable.

The constant-pressure specific heat (i.e., the constant-pressure heat capacity normalized by mass) is $$c_P=\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_{P,\ \ldots}$$
where $m$ is the mass, $U$ is the energy, $T$ is the temperature, $P$ is the pressure, and other constraints might be applied. One example of a constraint is a vertical configuration supported at the bottom. Because the center of mass rises by a distance of $\alpha L/2$ (where $\alpha$ is the linear coefficient of thermal expansion and $L$ is the length) for every degree of temperature increase, the system has to do work $\alpha mg L\Delta T/2$, where $g$ is the acceleration of gravity. Therefore,

$$c_{P,\,\mathrm{vertical}}=c_{P,\,\mathrm{horizontal}}+\frac{\alpha gL}{2}$$

(The presence of this extra term isn't all that unusual; we're already used to $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_{P}$ generally being larger than $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_{V}$ because the expanding system has to do work against the environment in the first case. The difference isn't large for condensed matter (because itdon't expand much with temperature) but is substantial with gases.)

The constant-pressure specific heat for copper is about 385 J kg<sup>-1</sup> K<sup>-1</sup> at room temperature and will increase by about 0.00008 J kg<sup>-1</sup> K<sup>-1</sup> for every meter of height if you stand a rod of it up.